# How to add local notification plugin in windows phone silver light Environment using worklight 7.1

Tags: c#, cordova, windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst, localnotification

We are developing hybrid mobile application using IBM Worklight 7.1. In this application we want to add local notification plugin, In android environment we successfully added, Now we are trying to add local notification plugin in windows phone silver light Environment.

Using below link we are  going to add local notification plugin in windows phone silver light 
[Adding Local notification plugin in windows phone silver light](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications)

In that link they provided .js files for native windows Environment, according to my knowledge .js files used for only windows Environment not for windows phone silver light. I need .cs files for the local notification plugin to add in windows phone silver light native Environment. Can any one  provide us .cs file for the local notification Plugin and need steps for how to add .cs file in windows phone silver light.

Comment: Did you add the plugin ? Use Cordova plugman to add the plugin and this should bring all the required files.
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/03.-Installation

Comment: can we add this plugman in worklight?. as of my knowledge we can't use cardova pluman to add plugin in worklight 7.1.

Comment: That's right, plugman is not supported in Hybrid apps generated by MobileFirst Studio.

Comment: So that is not useful for me right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to follow the integration suggestion as described in this blog post: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/08/03/integrating-3rd-party-cordova-plug-ins/

Or maybe implement one of your own: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/adding-native-functionality/windows-phone-8-adding-native-functionality-hybrid-application-apache-cordova-plugin/

If this does not work (and also take into account the notes and issues), my suggestion would be to try with MobileFirst Foundation 8.0, which provides full support for Codrova apps (you create a standard Cordova app, and MobileFirst SDK is a Cordova plug-in). This removes any hurdles you have encountered thus far and will enable you to use Cordova plug-man and other solutions.

Comment: we are the ending stage of the project. we don't want to change the MFP 7.1 to 8.0 because of so many plugins we used in 7.1 related and we don't no those are supported in MFP 8.0  so we need to do in MFP 7.1 only.

Comment: Those are your two options.

Comment: Idan it is possible to add local notification in windows environment? i added in android successful but i failed in windows

Comment: I don't know. We don't support 3rd party cordova plug-ins. You can either create your own plug-in that achieves this, or follow the possible workaround (the first link in my answer).

Comment: I take it my project windows environment from the worklight and import in visual studio and i am trying to adding the local notification but i am failed. what i am following the steps it is correct or not and i got this example from the google https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.

Comment: I already wrote to you what you should do. I can't help you any further.